# A clipboard issue: DOMException: Document is not focused

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I am making a Chrome web extension which fetches the HTML content of the current page and copy it to the clipboard by using a shortcut(Command + shift + Y in this case).

This is my code for the command listener:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
    if(command === 'save_page'){
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
            let url = tabs[0].url;
            //console.log(url)
            fetch(url)//fetch the HTML content by default(GET request)
                .then(response =>{
                    if(!response.ok) {
                        alert(`Failed to fetch URL: ${response.statusText}`)
                        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch URL: ${response.statusText}`)
                    }
                    return response.text()
                })//extract the text from the HTML
                .then(html => {
                    copyToClipboard(html)
                })
        });
    }
});
```

This is for the Clipboard:

```
async function copyToClipboard(text) {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
        console.log('Text copied to clipboard');
        alertBox('HTML content copied to clipboard!');


    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to copy text: ', err);
        alertBox('Failed to copy content to clipboard.');
    }
}
```

This is manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "__MSG_name__",
  "short_name": "Simple",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  "author": "Stefan vd",
  "homepage_url": "https://www.stefanvd.net/support/",
  "icons": {
    "19": "images/logo.png"
  },
   "background": {
     "service_worker": "scripts/popup.js"
   },
   "commands": {
     "save_page": {
       "suggested_key": {
         "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
         "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
       },
       "description": "Save the current page"
     }
   },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/logo.png"
    },
    "default_title": "__MSG_name__",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"   
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.stefanvd.net/*"],
      "js": ["scripts/popup.js", "scripts/alertbox.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; connect-src *; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "103",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": [ "activeTab" , "clipboardWrite", "tabs", "scripting","commands","downloads"]
}
```

So i tried to run it but i got a error : DOMException: Document is not focused. The weird thing is, the same code worked fine on a button clicking action.